# A patent for a specific wallet

Tags: search

Hi friends I would like to know if there is a patent for this wallet: http://zenlet.co
The ZENLET wallet

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRKNh.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1562350776/zenlet-amazingly-intuitive-wallet), there is the notation "[Patent pending]" below one of the pictures. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any patents where Zenlet was listed as the owner or assignee on either patents.google.com or www.lens.org/lens. At this point it gets tricky since the patent assignee might be the inventor and we don't know who that is and the actual inventor or patent number doesn't seem to come up in a Google search. You could try just searching for "wallet" on patents.google.com, but there are [17,168 hits](https://patents.google.com/?q=wallet&after=20131231) for documents after 2014. You best bet might be to contact Zenlet and ask.

Comment: I tried some combinations of wallet and rfid protection etc., but nothing sticks out. The name of the inventor would help a lot. Without it, this seems to be the only possible answer.